# how do I get my jmeter test plan to execute in Jenkins on my local windows machine?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jmeter

I'm trying to get My jmeter test plan to execute in Jenkins. Both jmeter and Jenkins are installed on my local windows machine. I've set up some properties in Jmeter and verified that I can run them from the cmd line successfully with this command: 
 `C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin>jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=2`
 Now in Jenkins I've created a new project, create two new parameters and entered the following in "execute shell" based off of exapmples I was able to find on the web.I haven't configured anything else in Jenkins. 
 `sh jmeter.sh -n -p user.properties -t C:/Users/MikeL/Documents/apache-jmeter/bin/testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1`
 suffice to say this script won't build my jmeter test. I recieve this error: 
 `Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\LOS API Regression Tests"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

If anybody has any clues I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this path `C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin` to your Environment Variables `PATH`.

Then Jenkins Build step should be **Windows Batch Command**

Then the command should be `jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1`

**Update:**
If you do not want to set the path, just directly give below command as Windows Batch Command.

`C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin\testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1`

---

Use either Ant/Maven/Gradle to run jmeter tests in the non-gui mode. They can also be integrated with Jenkins

- [JMeter-Ant](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/)
- [JMeter-Maven](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)

Comment: Thanks - I added that pathing to the path env variable and shortened my batch command as specified. The build still failed. here is the output:  
**Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\LOS API Regression Tests
[LOS API Regression Tests] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\hudson6684030616004371668.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\LOS API Regression Tests>jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1 
'jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**  any thoughts? Thks again

Comment: @cdav929, open command prompt. type jmeter and hit enter. What does it show??

Comment: When I open cmd propmpt its defaulted to the network drive "U". If I type jmeter there or switch to C: then type jmeter its telling me that '**jmeter is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**

Comment: however if I navigate to the bin folder of jmeter and then type "jmeter" it opens up jmeter's GUI interface.  

the last few entries of the "PATH" variable look like:  
**\; C:\WINDOWS\system32; C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin;**

Comment: @cdav929,check the update in my answer. Set that as windows batch command in jenkins

Comment: Perfect - that seemed to do the trick, thanks again.  I can now see the console output in Jenkins with test data.    However it does not seem to be using the choice parameter I chose in the dropdown or loging to the specified log.jtl file. Could this be because its now running as a batch command?

Comment: @cdav929, accept this as answer if it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is cross environment. you need to be running this with windows batch command instead of execute shell. windows wont recognize sh as executable.

```
C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin>jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=2
```

Run the above in execute windows batch mode

[image: Windows batch mode]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! makes sense, and I get a little further in the process now. However  I have the following line in the execute batch command text box in Jenkins:  C:\Users\mikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin\jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1

Comment: And when I execute the test in Jenkins I get this response:  
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\LOS API Regression Tests>C:\Users\mikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin\jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1
Could not open testApp.jmx 
Finished: SUCCESS'    
Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the output when u execute the command from command line?

Comment: This is my process for executing from the cmd prompt. First I open cmd prompt. It defaults to network drive U so I change dir to C:. then I navigate to the bin folder of jmeter. From the bin folder I type > **jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1**  
This starts jmeter and the output infoms me that it executed 37 tests with 1 failure as expected.